# Выставление оценок в таблицу из блоков

Tags: javascript

У меня есть таблица из блоков, допустим, в первом столбце имена, во втором - фамилии, а в третьем и дальше до n оценки должны стоять. Где-то в сторонке есть три блока: красный, желтый, зеленый; в которых написано 3, 4, 5 соответственно. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ячейку в таблице она заполнялась оценкой из выбранного блока и передавался в ячейку цвет блока? И так что если там есть другая оценка, то он заменял ее.

Comment: Как определить в какую ячейку заносить оценку при клике?

Comment: В какую ячейку кликаем, в ту и заносим.

Comment: а как выбирается цвет?Тоже по клику?

Comment: да.тоже по клику по одному из трех блоков с оценками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
table{width:200px;table-layout:fixed;}
table td{border:1px solid;height:100px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;}
.gallery{overflow:hidden}
.gallery div{width:100px;height:100px;margin:10px;float:left;text-align:center;font-size:20px;}
.gallery div.red{background:red;}
.gallery div.green{background:green;}
.gallery div.blue{background:blue;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php

?>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="gallery">
<div class="red">5</div>
<div class="green">4</div>
<div class="blue">3</div>
</div>
<script>

//var curcolor='green';
var arr=[];
arr["curcolor"]="green";
arr["mark"]=4;
var colorPiker=document.querySelectorAll("div.gallery div");
for(var i=0;i<colorPiker.length;i++){
    colorPiker[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        arr["curcolor"]=this.className;
        arr["mark"]=this.innerHTML;
        });
    }

var tdPiker=document.querySelectorAll("table td");

for(var i=0;i<tdPiker.length;i++){
    tdPiker[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor=arr["curcolor"];
        this.innerHTML=arr["mark"]
        })
}

</script>
```

Comment: а можно это же, не в таблицу,

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

 а для формочек, то есть 

     <div class="name"></div>
     <div class="marks">
     <form method="post" action="#">
     <input type="text" name="1" SIZE="1"></input>
     <input type="text" name="2" SIZE="1"></input>
     <input type="text" name="3" SIZE="1"></input>
     <input type="text" name="4" SIZE="1"></input>
     <input type="text" name="5" SIZE="1"></input>
     </form>
     </div>

Comment: И да можно поставить ограничение для ввода?чтобы человек не мог вводить сам в форму..только чтобы через сторонний блок информация копировалась?

Comment: Вы за готовым решение пришли?Я Вам дал прототип а дальше сами.Посмотрите атрибут readonly.

Comment: просто я с вашим прототипом и так вертел и так вертел...но в поле формы переносится цвет, но не переносится цифра

Comment: Получить/записать значение в поле нужно использовать свойство value

Comment: спасибо=)если я ничего не напутал this.value=arr[marks]...если все верно спасибо//только у меня еще один вопрос как обращаться к свойствам css?вы задали цвета по имени класса, а как через свойства стилей задать цвет?